# Create Twitter application programmatically

Tags: twitter

I am working on a project involving Twitter API and was wondering if there is a way I can create the Twitter application programmatically without going to : https://apps.twitter.com/

Comment: It makes sense if you'd indicate (a) your platform and (b) what options you've considered yourself.

Comment: I am using PHP 5.2. I am using the Twitter API to post tweets but was trying to find a way to create the Twitter application and obtain all needed credentials (Oath token, consumer key, consumer secret and Oath access token) programmatically. Is it possible ?

Comment: This link may give you a few pointers: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries

Comment: Thank you but I am using the api you referred me to and it doesn't enable you to create an application programmatically. You would still have to go through the apps.twitter site to create one

Answer (score 1):

While it may be technically feasible to create an application in this way, Twitter's processes are clearly intended to require that applications are created by submitting the form at https://apps.twitter.com/app/new

There is no functionality in the API to automate the creation of applications.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it. The process involves two steps.
The first step involves creating a link to a url that your user needs to visit in order to authorize the app. Once the user authorizes the app, Twitter will redirect the user to a call back page. The call back page will then make another call to Twitter to get the final tokens. Please refer to : 
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Using_OAuth_with_Twitter_-_PHP_Example for more details. You can also take a look at : https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged to get a better understanding about the process.
Thanks everyone for your input